# using css from a library in razor mvc3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an mvc 3 razor web application that uses several graphic components from a library.

I have set all the component in the library, I need to add a css file to the library but I dont know how to do it.

so how can I add a css file witch is a library ressource to a cshtml file.
I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
@section Styles {
<link href="@Url.Content("~/file.css")" />}
```

Comment: Does your `_Layout.cshtml` file contain a `@RenderSection("Styles")`?

Answer (score 2):

add the `rel=stylesheet` attribute to that link

Comment: thank you for your response,
I added   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
but the file is not reachable i think,
I placed it within the library and i want to call it from the cshtml file but I can't.